# How to remove multiple line breaks from a string

Tags: java, string, line-breaks

given a string i need to check if there are multiple line breaks (\n). If there are i need to convert them to one single line break.

Can you please show me code that does this? thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
s = s.replaceAll("(\r?\n){2,}", "$1");
```

Comment: If you need to do this a lot you can define `static final Pattern MERGE_LINEBREAKS = Pattern.compile("(\\r?\\n){2,}");` then you can use `s = MERGE_LINEBREAKS.matcher(s).replaceAll("$1");` which is a little nicer because you don't compile the regex every time.